# Postgres - ShareLock on Transaction

Tags: transactions, sqlalchemy, deadlock, postgresql-9.6

I am getting transaction deadlock while multiple processes try to insert the same row in a table. The only column with a non-null value in the insert is the one that has a unique constraint on it and is not a primary key. I am using SQLAlchemy version: 1.1.15, psycopg2 version: 2.7.3.2, python version: 3.4 and PostgreSQL version: 9.6.8 on Centos 7.

Here is the error I get before my process crashes:

```
psycopg2.extensions.TransactionDeadlockError: deadlock detected
DETAIL: Process X waits for ShareLock on transaction Z; blocked by process Y
Process Y waits for ShareLock on transaction W; blocked by process X
HINT: See server log for details
CONTEXT: while inserting index tuple (0, 125) in relation 'entity_short_name_unq'
```

Following is the definition of `entity` table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.entity
(
    entity_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('entity_entity_id_seq'::regclass),
    name character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    short_name character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    description text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT pk_entity PRIMARY KEY (entity_id),
    CONSTRAINT entity_name_unq UNIQUE (name) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    CONSTRAINT entity_short_name_unq UNIQUE (short_name) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

The statement that is causing deadlock according to database logs is:

```
begin;
insert into entity (name, short_name, description) values(null, 'LLL', null);
commit;
```

I was able to reproduce the error by opening three terminals, connecting to the database in each of those and issuing the above three commands in a transaction making sure that all three transactions (A,B,C) issue insert query before I issue commit in any of those.

The transaction that issued the insert query first (say A), succeeds on commit. One of the other two transaction (say B) reports integrity error for violating unique constraint but the other (say C) displays deadlock error.

Why doesn't C report integrity error as B?
What can I do to avoid this deadlock?

Comment: You should post this to the [Postgres mailing list](https://www.postgresql.org/list/)

Comment: This does not seem very related to [tag:sqlalchemy].